# Django - a href duplicate target

Tags: html, django, hyperlink

I run into a weird issue in my first Django project. In my view I have a function that generates a link dynamically based on certain form values:

```
return '<p style="font-style:italic;"> <a href="' + baseURL +  str(xyz.pk)  +  '">Some text</a></p>'
```

When I print the output in the console it shows the correct link in example:

```
<a href="127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/20824305-d4e7-4dbd-992c-7b57bb5e477f">
```

I return the result of the function in my view:

```
return render(request, 'xyz/xyz.html', {'form':form, 'url_text': generateAccessURLs(request,xyz), 'current_path': current_path })
```

But when I run the app and open it in the browser the target URL gets duplicated. In the HTML it looks like this:

```
<a href="127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/ea0de6a5-5bcf-4c52-8032-dc865d660a0d">Some text</a>
```

but when i click on the link it opens

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/20824305-d4e7-4dbd-992c-7b57bb5e477f/127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/ea0de6a5-5bcf-4c52-8032-dc865d660a0d
```

In my template i have simply this: `{{url_text|safe}}`

What am I overlooking here?

Browser: Chrome, also tested deployed on a server rather than localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Django. Your link does not start with a scheme (i.e. `http` or `https`), so your browser thinks that `127.0.0.1` is a path, not a hostname. Prepend your `baseURL` with `http://` or simply `//`. For example:

```
return '<p style="font-style:italic;"> <a href="//' + baseURL +  str(xyz.pk)  +  '">Some text</a></p>'
```